# Менеджеры компоновки, QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, qlayout, qgridlayout, qpalette

Пишу игру, напоминающую кубик рубика. 
Для грани я создал окно классом `gameForm()`,  в котором с помощью `QGridLayout` хочу вставить еще виджет созданный классом `ActionForm()`, со своим цветом, 
но в результате получаю пустое окно.

**main.py**:

```
class gameForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.COLORS = ["red", "yellow", "green"]
        self.resize(200, 200)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)
        grid = self.initMap(grid)

    def initMap(self, grid):
        i = 0
        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                w = ActionForm(x, y, self.COLORS[i])  
                grid.addWidget(w, y, x)
            i+=1
        return grid
```

---

Виджет для вставки ячейки грани:

```
class ActionForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, x, y,  color):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(x, y, color)

    def initUI(self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = QColor(color)
        self.setColor(color)
        self.set_playable(x, y)

    def setColor(self, color):
        appearance = self.palette()
        appearance.setColor(QPalette.Normal, QPalette.Window, QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(appearance)
```

---

Помогите, пожалуйста, буду премного благодарен. 
P.S. Сильно не ругайтесь на оформление моего вопроса, если что-то некорректно, это мой первый раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **autoFillBackground : bool**
>
> Это свойство определяет, будет ли фон виджета заполнен автоматически.
> Установите `self.setAutoFillBackground(True)` иначе он будет прозрачным из-за влияния родительского окна.

Подробнее здесь: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class ActionForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, x, y,  color):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(x, y, color)

    def initUI(self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = QColor(color)
        self.setColor(color)
# ?        self.set_playable(x, y)                                   # ???

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)                             # <------<<< +++
        appearance = self.palette()
        appearance.setColor(QPalette.Normal, QPalette.Window, QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(appearance)
        
        
class gameForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.COLORS = ["red", "yellow", "green"]
        self.resize(200, 200)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)
        grid = self.initMap(grid)

    def initMap(self, grid):
        i = 0
        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                w = ActionForm(x, y, self.COLORS[i])  
                grid.addWidget(w, y, x)
            i+=1
        return grid
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication([])
    w = gameForm()
    w.resize(300, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]